# Error 150 : table couldn't be created

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

Where am I going wrong? I get the error 150 debit_card table couldn't be created. Something to do the foreign keys i know, just don't know what exactly. Help?

```
create table customer(
cust_id int auto_increment,
first_name varchar(25),
last_name varchar(25),
street varchar(25),
city varchar(25),
state char(2),
zip varchar(10),
CONSTRAINT customer_pk primary key(cust_id)
);

create table card_account(
acct_no char(16),
exp_date date,
card_type ENUM("Debit","Credit") not null,
CONSTRAINT card_account_pk primary key(acct_no,exp_date)
);

create table debit_card(
bank_no char(9) not null,
acct_no char(16),
exp_date date,
CONSTRAINT debit_card_pk primary key(acct_no,exp_date),
CONSTRAINT debit_card_acct_no_fk foreign key(acct_no) references card_account(acct_no) on delete cascade,
CONSTRAINT debit_card_exp_date_fk foreign key(exp_date) references card_account(exp_date) on delete cascade
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `card_account` table has a `composite primary key`. You cannot use those columns separately in a `foreign key` constraint.

But you can add a `foreign key` referencing to the `composite primary key`:

```
create table debit_card(
bank_no char(9) not null,
acct_no char(16),
exp_date date,
CONSTRAINT debit_card_pk primary key(acct_no,exp_date),
CONSTRAINT debit_card_acct_no_fk foreign key(acct_no,exp_date) references card_account(acct_no,exp_date) on delete cascade
);
```